# Laravel 8 API : Get with id return empty json

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-8

I have a really big problem, i tried to make an API with Laravel 8 but when I use Get method to get all my facts it works and I get all of them, but when an id is used I always have empty json...

```
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param Facts $facts
     * @return Facts
     */
    public function show(Facts $facts)
    {
        dd($facts);
        return $facts;
    }
```

And I get this instead of my data

```
App\Models\Facts {#1195
  #fillable: array:6 [
    0 => "type"
    1 => "deleted"
    2 => "text"
    3 => "used"
    4 => "verified"
    5 => "count"
  ]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

And this is the route to go on the controller.

`Route::apiResource('facts', FactsController::class);`

I'm sorry my english is not perfect but if you can help me please... Thanks for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to

```
public function show(Facts $fact)
{

   return $fact;
}
```

To verify run

```
php artisan route:list
```

Even if your api resource name is plural `facts` still params are singular.

For example

```
api/facts/{fact}   | facts.show
```

Comment: That's exactly what I have in my routes... I will try to change facts by fact

Comment: @VincentB.still you have issue ?

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! just for a "s" at facts, by the way laravel write it alone... xD Thanks for all man!